# JBoss ESB: Using HTTPRouter with a secure endpoint and no keystore

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, esb

I am attempting to create a HTTPRouter action (within an esb) which sends some XML to an external URL. The URL is secure, but has a self signed certificate which I do not have the keystore for. Below is the XML I'm writing to set up the HTTPRouter.

http://pastebin.com/FmFYU5e4

In the ht.props file there is only one property set. I am defining the protocol socket factory to be the SelfSignedSSLProtocolSocketFactoryBuilder.

```
#HttpProtocol Config...
protocol-socket-factory=org.jboss.soa.esb.http.protocol.SelfSignedSSLProtocolSocketFactoryBuilder
```

When I deploy the ESB, I am getting the following error:

```
org.jboss.soa.esb.ConfigurationException: Failed to locate keystore '/keystore'
```

Reading around the various forums on the topic, it seems that the HTTPRouter action wants a keystore file to be defined. As mentioned, I do not have one as the external endpoint is not created or controlled by myself. Is there a way to get the HTTPRouter action to work for a secure endpoint with no keystore defined? Is the way I am defining the endpoint correct?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have SelfSignedSSLProtocolSocketFactoryBuilder without keystore. Create self-signed one using the JDK keytool command and put it under correct path:

```
openssl genrsa -out cert.key 1024 && echo -ne "\n\n\n\n\n$HOSTNAME\nroot@$HOSTNAME\n" | openssl req -new -key cert.key -x509 -out cert.crt -days 999
openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.crt -out cert.der
keytool -import -file cert.der -alias root -keystore /cesta/ke/keystore.jks
```

I am not sure about "root" alias. Should work, but maybe you need different alias name. More details how to configure (parameter names): http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/JBoss/jbossesb-4.7/org/jboss/soa/esb/http/protocol/AbstractProtocolSocketFactoryBuilder.java.htm

Comment: Hi lzap. Thanks for the response. Within the commands you specify, you refer to a cert.key and cert.crt. Are these generated by the commands? Also, the HOSTNAME string you specify, is that the URL I am attempting to point to? As I said in my description, all I have is the external URL. I have no cert files with it.

Comment: Ok, I've worked out the problem. I do need to create the keystore and truststore files. I first had to extract the .cer file from the URL I am attempting to POST to. Once I had this file, I could create the keystore and trust files. I followed the steps outlined in the tutorial below:

http://www.techbrainwave.com/?p=953

Also, rather than using SelfSignedSSLProtocolSocketFactoryBuilder, I used EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory found in apache httpclient. I'm getting a 100 code at the moment but I seem to be progressing!

Thanks lpaz for highlighting the need for the keystore and truststore files.